# Sorting an array in O(n) using dictionary?

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm, sorting, dictionary

Assuming you have an array of numbers that need to be sorted and the following two conditions are true:

1. A low standard deviation
2. Memory isn't a constraint

How about using dictionary to sort this in O(n), below is the python code:

```
def sortArray(nums: List[int]) -> List[int]:

    # dictionary to store all the numbers in the array as key and number of occurrences as value
    d = {} 
    
    # Keep a track of upper and lower bound of array
    max_num = nums[0]
    min_num = nums[0]
    
    for e in nums:
        if e>max:
            max=e
        if e<min:
            min=e
            
        try:
        #increment the value for "e" if it exists in dictionary
            d[e]=d[e]+1  
        except:
        #add a new key "e"
            d[e]=1 
    
    a=[]
    for i in range(min_num,max_num+1):
        try:
            for j in range(0,d[i]):
                # add the element in new array for d[i] times
                a.append(i)
        except:
            continue
            
    return a
```

Given the 2 conditions,Are there any scenarios where this code would not work in O(n)? Is there something wrong with this approach ?

Comment: This algorithm is known as [Counting Sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort). Please also see [this post on CS](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/86466/what-is-the-precise-definition-of-pseudo-polynomial-time-feat-counting-sort) where it's explained why it's not, in general, a linear time algorithm

Comment: beware, `max` and `min` are built-in functions

Comment: This is counting sort

Comment: The standard deviation is less important than the range. Even with a small standard deviation you can get an extreme outlier which kills the performance.

Comment: To do this correctly, you would need a preprocessing loop that calculates the mean and standard deviation. Then if it makes sense to proceed (i.e. the range that covers three standard deviations is O(n)), make an array for counting the numbers inside three standard deviations, a list of numbers more than three standard deviations below the mean (the small outliers), and another list of numbers of the large outliers. Sort the small outliers. Append the central numbers using a standard counting sort. Sort and append the large outliers.

Comment: Worst case performance of the code in the question is O(N^1.5) when N = 6σ

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to tell the exact complexity of this procedure because the running time depends on the range of the values, among others.

If this range is fixed, the final double loop adds an element N times. Hence O(N), if the hash table guarantees an O(N) complexity.

But for unbounded N, a fixed range does not make much sense, and it should grow with N. Hence the complexity will be of order O(M(N) + N), where M(N) is the size of the range.

It is also worth to note that the append operation does not necessarily feature constant time cost per element.